# Yahoo Pipes: More complex RSS output?

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

I've been working with pipes for a while now, I am trying to output more than the basic structure of:

- Item

  - title

    link

    description

    guid

    pubDate

I want to publish more data in the RSS feed under different fields but cannot figure out if this is even possible.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks javed for the suggestion.  It's an interesting product and I will take a look at it when I get a lot of time to explore.  However, right now I need to get this done with pipes if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This post at the Yahoo Pipes blog goes through the basics of building a complex RSS feed with a couple examples.

http://blog.pipes.yahoo.net/2009/06/10/new-create-rss-and-rss-item-builder-modules/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not related to yahoo pipes, but if you are looking for etl tools, i found yahoo pipes very limiting. I have had the best luck with Open Kapow. Just in case you have not heard about/used it.